# What is the meaning of this message StorageProxy.java:2358 - Schemas are in agreement from Cassandra debug.log

Tags: cassandra

What is the meaning of these message continuously getting in Cassandra debug.logs.
Whether these messages are good or bad for cluster health ?

```
DEBUG [pool-1-thread-3] 2020-01-21 17:16:35,278 StorageProxy.java:2358 - Schemas are in agreement.
DEBUG [pool-1-thread-5] 2020-01-21 17:16:45,256 StorageProxy.java:2358 - Schemas are in agreement.
DEBUG [pool-1-thread-1] 2020-01-21 17:16:55,278 StorageProxy.java:2358 - Schemas are in agreement.
```

Comment: Is any update ?

Comment: What is happening Cassandra internally while getting these messages ?
please confirm, weather these messages are Harm in PROD ? or not ?

DEBUG [pool-1-thread-4] 2020-01-31 13:49:46,704 StorageProxy.java:2358 - Schemas are in agreement.
DEBUG [pool-1-thread-5] 2020-01-31 13:49:56,707 StorageProxy.java:2358 - Schemas are in agreement.